# SPI Clk transitions to idle state but no data transfer

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, spi, android-things

I am attempting to run an SPI demo on android things. Currently I am able to view the CLK line transitioning to the correct idle state after I call all configuration parameters, including setMode. However, whenever I call write(), I do not see the CLK line transitioning.

I have tried several Pi's and am confused as to what I might be missing.
If anyone else has seen this, please shed some light.

I am using the Apa102 sample code found here:
https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/rainbowhat

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more about what you have connected to your RPi hardware (Rainbow HAT, etc.), and where you are measuring the signal?

Comment: @Devunwired thanks for asking. The pi is currently only hooked up to a bitscope micro for observing the pin states. I am starting to suspect that the Pi is working but the signals are being under sampled. http://my.bitscope.com/store/?p=view&i=item+0

Answer (score 1):

Can't close my own question. It turns out my test bed was setup incorrectly. The Pi was functioning as expected all along. I verified this after buying an SPI compatible sensor and reading data from it.